# Setting up react-native android environment on windows, ADB devices not showing up through bash, but show up in regular cmd prompt

Tags: android, bash, react-native

I am trying to get an environment on windows set up so I can develop react-native android apps.

So far I've gone through a quickstart guide for setting up react native CLI.

1. I've got Node and python2, and I have the current jdk
2. Android studio is already set up, I've set user variables for ANDROID_HOME
3. I've setup Windows Linux Subsystem 2 and bash
4. I've created a new react-native project in a folder on my desktop

My problem currently is recognizing an android device through ADB. I can see both my physical device and emulated device in the regular windows cmd shell, ADB (version 41) but the latest version in my ubuntu subsystem is 39, so I can't launch the basic app through bash. That is to say, when I run adb devices in bash nothing shows up. I've read that you need to have the same version for it to be recognized but I replaced version 41 with 39 at my android sdk / tools path and windows cmd stopped recognizing it.

Looking for some insight, if i'm going in the right direction, etc.

Comment: *" can see both my physical device and emulated device....."* . Please edit your Q to show the exact commands and the exact output that illustrates your issue. As is, we have no way of knowing what you are seeing and why it might not be working. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: My bad. I ended up copying the adb.exe from its location and overwriting the adb file in the WLS with it, and it seemed to fix the problem.